# Website validates but does not render with HTML DocType

Tags: validation, doctype

Hello
I built a website for a graphic design company (www.brgdonline.com) and used the  tag. The webpage will not show up at all in Chrome, Firefox, or IE. However, if I remove the doctype completely, it shows up fine. I have validated the website using w3's validator and got no errors. I can see the source code just fine even when it doesn't render.

Thanks so much in advance.

RMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with id #whole has `height:100%` and `overflow:hidden`. The height is set to 100% of body which has no height defined and therefore becomes 0. Remove `height:100%` and `overflow:hidden` from `#whole` and I think it will render again.
alternatively give `body` and `html` a `height:100%` so they fill the whole viewport height.

Comment: in short #whole has a height of 100% of an element with no height (body), so it becomes 0px high

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help but I set all three (html, body, whole) to 1024px (fiddled with the width too) and still see nothing.

Comment: I apologize that did actually work. I just forgot to re-upload it (embarrassing).  Thank you so much!